# Android TableRow with text under image,multi line TextViews

Tags: android, tableview, tablerow

I need to add following format rows for Android TableView. Can someone please help me to do this?[image]

Thanks.

Comment: is it compulsary to do this with Tableview?

Comment: post the xml that you have tried

Comment: I think you need List Item design like this.

Comment: No,I can add data in columns using <TableLayout> <TextView ..../> <TextView ..../> <TextView ..../></TableLayout>. But I think if I can add image with TextView like this it is better than now. But I don't know how to add image with text like this

Comment: @Balvinder Sing.But how to add images,texts to ListView?Like this order?

Comment: What you want to do please exact ask that problem

Comment: @Tangle You have to make seperate xml for ListItem design. You can make this design by using Linear Layout without any problem. And with the help of Custom adapter of the list you can Inflate this design in your List view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this layout.

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/enaiv" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Android TableLayout** going to be arranged groups of views into rows and columns. You will use the  element to build a row in the table. Each row has zero or more cells; each cell can hold one View object

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=307